# Migrate User from production DB of ASP.NET MVC app to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, passwords, database-migration

I'm having a production MVC Website with 500 registered users in the database (MS SQL). I'm thinking of rewrite the app in Rails for many reasons.

The question that popup first is that how can I move username/password from MS SQL to MySQL without knowing that the password is ( the passwords in database are hashed).

Answer (score 0):

Since password hashing is practically irreversible by design, you only have two options:

1. **Replicate the hashing algorithm** used in your ASP.NET MVC app.
    Move the database without changes.
2. **Nullify these hashes**.
    On any login attempt prompt the user to reset password if the password hash is `nil` (`NULL`, or "does not exist").

I have seen option (2) in action a lot of times, namely on Logitech website.